# (Solved) Exact functors commute with homology

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

I want to show that for any exact functor $F\colon {}_R\mathrm{Mod}\rightarrow {}_S\mathrm{Mod}$ there is a natural isomorphism 
$$F\circ H_n \cong H_n \circ \mathbf{Ch}(F)$$
where $\mathbf{Ch}(F)$ denotes the induced map on chain complexes. I have already done this the boring way, writing out an isomorphism and showing commutativity of the appropriate diagrams.

**Question:** Is there some better (read: computation-free) way of doing this? Specifically, is it possible to realize the isomorphism as a connecting homomorphism in an LES of homology modules (and then just refer to naturality of connecting homomorphisms)?

**My efforts:** Consider a chain complex $C_\bullet$. We have associated chain complexes

1. $Z_\bullet$ = chain complex of cycles with all differentials $0$.
2. $B_\bullet$ = chain complex of boundaries with all differentials $0$.
3. $H_\bullet$ = chain complex of homology modules (!) with all differentials $0$.

These assemble into an SES of chain complexes:
$$
0 \rightarrow B_\bullet \rightarrow Z_\bullet \rightarrow H_\bullet \rightarrow 0.
$$
An easy argument shows that $F$ exact $\Rightarrow \mathbf{Ch}(F)$ exact. Hence we have the following SES of chain complexes in ${}_S\mathrm{Mod}$:
$$
0\rightarrow FB_\bullet \rightarrow FZ_\bullet \rightarrow FH_\bullet \rightarrow 0.
$$
The corresponding LES in homology is then (since all differentials are zero):
$$
\dots \rightarrow FB_n\rightarrow FZ_n \rightarrow FH_n \xrightarrow \partial FB_{n-1}\rightarrow FZ_{n-1}\rightarrow \dots
$$
Here I realize that what I really want is for $\partial$ to go from e.g. $FH_n$ to $H_n(FC_\bullet )$ (or the other way around), not to mention the fact that I want flanking zero maps. In that case, I really want to look at a different SES of chain complexes, probably involving $FC_\bullet$ directly. It also seems that the "right" SES of chain complexes will involve one of the chain complexes already mentioned, but shifted so that degrees match up.

Can someone give me a hint as to the chain complexes I should be looking at?

**Update (solved).** As suggested by Max in the comments, one can consider the SES of chain complexes
$$
0 \rightarrow Z_\bullet\rightarrow C_\bullet \xrightarrow d B_{\bullet - 1} \rightarrow 0,
$$
where $d$ is the differential. Proceeding as above, we now find the following LES in homology (after first applying $F$):
$$
\dots \rightarrow H_{n+1} (FC_\bullet )\xrightarrow 0 FB_n \xrightarrow \partial FZ_n \rightarrow H_n(FC_\bullet ) \xrightarrow 0 \dots
$$
from which we extract
$$
0 \rightarrow FB_n \xrightarrow \partial FZ_n \rightarrow H_n(FC_\bullet )\rightarrow 0.
$$
The conclusion should now follow from naturality of $\partial$.

Comment: $H_\bullet$ is not a chain complex now, is it ?

Comment: It is, I set all differentials to be $0$.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at something of the form $0\to Z_\bullet \to C_\bullet \to B_{\bullet -1}\to 0$ where the maps are the inclusion and the differential respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I think I saw that in a proof of the universal coefficient theorem/Kunneth once, might have been trying (and failing) to mimic something of that kind subconsciously :)

Comment: This is also where I got the idea from, and it can easily be generalized to a left (right) exact functor to get a "universal coefficient theorem" for this functor in terms of the right/left derived functors (except that here by exactness this will yield what we want)

Comment: Sorry for digging up an old question.  At the end of the proof, I don't see why the conclusion follows from "naturality of $\delta$".  I do see how the SES $0 \to FB_n \to FZ_n \to H_n(FC) \to 0$ implies the result though because this implies that $H_n(FC) \cong FZ_n/FB_n$ and we also have the SES $0 \to B_n \to Z_n \to H_n(C) \to 0$ which implies $0 \to FB_n \to FZ_n \to F(H_n(C)) \to 0$ so $F(H_n(C)) \cong FZ_n/FB_n \cong H_n(FC) $ as needed. Thank you.

Comment: @Khoa ta this may sound dumb (because everything is obvious when checked explicitly), but back then I wanted (just for fun) a fancier way to see that the isomorphism $F(H_n(C_\bullet ))\cong H_n(FC_\bullet )$ is natural in the chain cplx $C_\bullet$, and my guess was that this could be deduced from naturality of $\delta$. This is the part of the statement that I'm referring to when I say the conclusion follows.

Comment: The existence of some isomorphism is as you say obvious from having a short exact sequence, but we really need naturality of $\delta$ in $C_\bullet$ in order to conclude that the isomorphism is natural in $C_\bullet$ also.

Comment: Ah, I see, so you also tried to show the isomorphism is natural as well by using naturality of $\delta$.  Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: How do you see that the naturality of $\partial$ implies that the isomorphism is natural in $C_.$?

Comment: I see that for each $C_.$ there is an isomorphism $\eta_C:FH_n(C)\rightarrow H_n\textbf{Ch}(F)(C)$ by the universal property of cokernel. These isomorphisms $\eta_C$ (might potentially) form components of a natural isomorphism $\eta:FH_n\Rightarrow H_n\textbf{Ch}(F)$. I also know that the cokernel above is cokernel of the natural connecting morphism $\partial$. But I am unable to show that $\eta$ is indeed a natural transformation.